# using zend test dbadapter with zend db table abstract

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table, zend-test

Has anyone been able to to use Zend_Test_DbAdapter with Zend_Db_Table_Abstract?

I'm trying to test a Model I created that extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract and I get an exception regarding the primary key not being set if I use a Zend_Test_DbAdapter (other adapters like mysql or sqlite) work fine.

---

```
class Model_Category extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'categories';

    protected $_dependentTables = array('Model_Video');

    public function getMap()
    {
        $map = array();
        $rows = $this->fetchAll();
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            $map[$row->id] = $row->name;
        }

        return $map;
    }
}
```

---

Snippet from a PHPUnit test class:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $adapter = new Zend_Test_DbAdapter();
    $stmt = Zend_Test_DbStatement::createSelectStatement(array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'pranks'),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'physical_feats'),
        array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'art'),
        array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'cute'),
        array('id' => 5, 'name' => 'philanthropy')
    ));
    $adapter->appendStatementToStack($stmt);

    $this->fixture = new Model_Category($adapter);
}
```

Exceptions are thrown when exercising the Model's methods:

```
public function testGetMap()
{
    $expected = array(
        '1' => 'pranks',
        '2' => 'physical_feats',
        '3' => 'art',
        '4' => 'cute',
        '5' => 'philanthropy'
    );
    $actual = $this->fixture->getMap();
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
}
```

Results in:

```
Model_CategoryTest::testGetMap()
Zend_Db_Table_Exception: A table must have a primary key, but none was found
ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php:876
ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php:969
ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Db/Table/Select.php:100
ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Db/Table/Select.php:78
ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php:1005
ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php:1303
application/models/Category.php:35
tests/unit/application/models/CategoryTest.php:90
```

---

Forcing a primary key does not work either:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $adapter = new Zend_Test_DbAdapter();
    $stmt = Zend_Test_DbStatement::createSelectStatement(array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'pranks'),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'physical_feats'),
        array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'art'),
        array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'cute'),
        array('id' => 5, 'name' => 'philanthropy')
    ));
    $adapter->appendStatementToStack($stmt);

    $this->fixture = new Model_Category(array(
        'db' => $adapter,
        'primary' => 'id'
    ));
}
```

Executing the same unit test, from above results in:

```
Model_CategoryTest::testGetMap()
Zend_Db_Table_Exception: Primary key column(s) (id) are not columns in this table ()
ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php:888
ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php:969
ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Db/Table/Select.php:100
ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Db/Table/Select.php:78
ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php:1005
ZendFramework-1.10.6/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php:1303
application/models/Category.php:35
tests/unit/application/models/CategoryTest.php:93
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your model and what the stack trace of the exception is?

Comment: I've added code and strack traces to my original post. I hope this helps.I should mention that the line numbers listed for Category.php and CategoryTest.php in the traces are wrong because I have condensed the source code for this post.

Comment: In both cases the trace is referring to "$rows = $this->fetchAll()" in Category.php, and "$actual = $this->fixture->getMap();" in CategoryTest.php.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the primary key by doing the following on your Zend_Test_DbAdapter instance:

```
$adapter = new Zend_Test_DbAdapter();
$adapter->setDescribeTable('table_name', array('column_name' =>
    array(
        'SCHEMA_NAME' => 'schema_name',
        'TABLE_NAME'  => 'table_name'
        'COLUMN_NAME' => 'column_name',     
        'PRIMARY'     => true
    )
));
```

And then transposing table_name, column_name and schema_name with the values from your implementation. You would need to do this for every table you are interacting with in the class under test.

Comment: That solved part of the issue but exposed a new related problem. When Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract's fetchPairs() method is called, $row[0] and $row[1] don't exist. That is because somehow $stmt->fetch(Zend_Db::FETCH_NUM) still returns an associative array, not a numeric array.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the exception `Zend_Db_Table_Exception: A table must have a primary key, but none was found` is because all tables that use `Zend_Db_Table` must have a primary key defined.  When you go to use the table, since a primary key was not defined in your `DbTable` class, Zend_Db attempts to determine the table's primary key by examining the table's properties from the information schema.  It sees your table doesn't have a primary key and fails.

From the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.defining.primary-key):

> If you don't specify the primary key, **`Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`** tries to
>   discover the primary key based on the information provided by the
>   **`describeTable()`** method.
>
> **Note: Every table class must know which columns can be used to address
>   rows uniquely. If no primary key columns are specified in the table
>   class definition or the table constructor arguments, or discovered in
>   the table metadata provided by **`describeTable()`**, then the table cannot
>   be used with **`Zend_Db_Table`**.

Trying to force the primary key isn't working because it looks like your table doesn't have a column called `id` which you are specifying as the primary key.

The solution would be to add a primary key to the table you are trying to use.

In your model class that extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` you can specify a primary key that isn't ID using `protected $_primary = 'primary_column';`

Comment: Thanks for the response! The problem is I'm trying to use a Zend_Test_DbAdapter for testing. That adapter does not connect to a real database and thus has no concept of table metadata (as far as I know).

Comment: That's true but it extends from `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` which performs this check very early in construction so that's why you're getting the error.  It testing, you still need to set a primary key which you would have to do in production anyway.  Adding the definition for the primary key should get past the error.

Comment: As I stated before Zend_Test_DbAdapter has no concept of metadata, therefor no column can be set as the primary key. In the end I think you answered my question- because Zend_Db_Table_Abstract requires a primary key, the Zend_Test_DbAdapter cannot be used. That is a shame...

Comment: It just seems like if you added a dummy `protected $_primary = 'id';` to your Category model the error should go away.